# Receive USSD data in application

Tags: android

is it possible to receive data sent through USSD sessions in an android mobile application? data such as transaction id.
we want to design an application running some USSD codes and after that, the server will send the mobile phone some data such as transaction id. we want to receive this piece of info and show it in the application.

Answer (score 1):

USSD is not yet supported on Android. There is a feature request for it: [go this link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1285)

and also you can go for  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225100/how-to-run-ussd-commands-on-android)