# Android set or reset SIM card PIN code programmatically

Tags: java, android

I have implemented below given to unlock my app (this code works for only systems apps so I have done my app as system app )

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int state = manager.getSimState();

if(state == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PIN_REQUIRED || state == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_PUK_REQUIRED)
{
   try {

      @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
      Class clazz = Class.forName(manager.getClass().getName());

       Method m = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
       m.setAccessible(true);
       ITelephony it = (ITelephony) m.invoke(manager);
       if (it.supplyPin(simPin)) {
           Toast.makeText(context,"SIM UnLocked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(context,"SIM UNLOCK FAILED",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    // 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}else{
    Toast.makeText(context,"SIM is not Locked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

It works fine for me, but now I need to implement setting or resetting SIM PIN programmatically, let me know if it is possible or not. if possible than how can I implement that?

Comment: AFAIK you can execute USSD codes for that. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225100/how-to-run-ussd-commands-on-android and find the USSD to set/change the pin. I think it can work

Comment: thanks @PedroOliveira for your responce. but how I can send request for PIN change?

Comment: You can get more info here http://berlin.ccc.de/~tobias/mmi-ussd-ss-codes-explained.html. check the "SIM control codes" part

Comment: but I think pin is saved at SIM (Locally). I dont think when change pin code we send request to network, but I think it is saved to SIM locally without any network request. if I am wrong let me know

Comment: You're right. But this code is executed locally. You don't have to press Call to execute this code. However, after some search, I don't think you can use an intent to execute this code. But it's worth the try. Try executing the code on your phone numpad and then try it using an intent

Comment: @PedroOliveira, it worked for me but I cant confirm programmatically wether PIN is set or Not. I have tried with onActivityResult() whether PIN changed or nor, the resultCode is 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String ussdCode = "**04*"+oldPin+"*"+newPin+"*"+newPin+"#";
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:" + ussdCode)));
```