# Android SIM exclusivity

Tags: android, locking, block, unlock

I'm developing an application do be distributed with phones and data enabled cards, for the sole purpose of running it. The manager wants the users to not be able to make calls or go to the internet, except through the application. The SIM card should not be usable in other phones either.

So I'm thinking of an app that would block most of the interaction with the base android system, and the SIM card would be locked with its PIN.

When the app is launched, I want it to provide the PIN to be able to communicate, but when it loses focus (onPause) it would still require the PIN code for the other apps, like the dialer or the browser to use it.
I've seen people sharing code to provide the pin and unlock (couldn't get it to work yet), but not to lock the SIM again.

Can this be done? If not how would you go about meeting these requirements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code so far

Comment: I'm still trying to unlock the pin, following this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25784141/android-set-or-reset-sim-card-pin-code-programmatically and others that more or less follow the same path. It's not working for me yet, but I can't find anything about locking the system again. So if I'm successful in unlocking, then I leave the card vulnerable to the system. Let's face it, there is always a way of bypassing an app that tries to block the system, even if it is by loading another app with adb via USB cable!