# I need to execute some task oriented on some dates. Can i do it with native android api

Tags: android

I need to execute some task oriented on some dates. Can i do it with native android api. And once more question i need to execute ussd request in background mode. Can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a task on a certain date you should use alarm manager, which you can take a look at here -

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

I am not quite sure what you are asking in the second part of you question, but here is a link on ussds in android

- [How is it possible to do USSD requests on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477597/how-is-it-possible-to-do-ussd-requests-on-android)

If you want to preform this action while you app is not running you would also use the alarm manager for that.