# How to make a special call and get result in android?

Tags: android

I want to dial a special number like

> *123#

which is a network request and get result sent by network.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Do you really expect a yes/no answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is it possible to do USSD requests on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477597/how-is-it-possible-to-do-ussd-requests-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

```
Intent calling=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

if ( phno.contains( "#" ))
    phno = Uri.encode(phno+"#");

calling.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+( phno ) ) );

startActivity(calli);
```

Note:

Here **phno** is `String` that contains phone number like *123# or 123456789

Comment: The actual answer lies in [Mohsen Afshin's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477597/how-is-it-possible-to-do-ussd-requests-on-android).