# Hash (#) gets stripped from sent USSD

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to send a USSD code for example **`*1411#`** but the problem is the **`#`** symbol gets removed and the phone will dial to **`*1411`**   not **`*1411#`**

```
  if Assigned(PhoneDialerService) then
  begin
    if edtCardNumber.Text <> '' then
      PhoneDialerService.Call('*1411#')
    else
      ShowMessage('Error');
  end;
```

If the `PhoneDialerService.Call` can't send USSD code what alternative do I use instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found it :)

```
  if Assigned(PhoneDialerService) then
  begin
    if edtCardNumber.Text <> '' then
      PhoneDialerService.Call('*1411'+JStringToString(TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.encode(StringToJString('#'))))
    else
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error');
      edtCardNumber.SetFocus;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: +1, well done; do you happen to have a link where you found that info?

Comment: @Johan see in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477597/how-is-it-possible-to-do-ussd-requests-on-android) in jave programming they use `String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");` then i try to use the  'Uri.encode'  in delphi :)

Comment: Since you are hard-coding the number, you can hard-code the encoding as well, to avoid all the redundant conversions and allocations: `PhoneDialerService.Call('*1411%23');`