# How to get operator features android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Is there a way to get a user's operator features like internet quota, free minutes, credits by programming with java? Or maybe you can help me with your ideas?

Comment: Doubt it. Who says the operator even *has* a concept of free minutes?

Comment: @immibis I guess he's talking about SIM service provider.

Comment: @Apurva Yes. If I pay $X/month for unlimited minutes, how many free minutes do I have? You could say "infinity", because using more wouldn't cost me anything... or the number of minutes left in the month, or "zero", because I'm paying for them.

Answer (score 1):

That operator feature or SIM service provider detail are called as USSD request.

You can intercept that USSD response. for more detail just check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452464/801369).